# How do I correctly implement an instance Eq for a data type with constructors?

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass, definition, algebraic-data-types

I am implementing an `instance Eq` for `MyNum` data type that has *Fractions* and *Mixed Numbers* as data constructors (each one with its own arguments).

I am also using a `helper` function to convert from `MyNum` to `Rational`. This should help me reduce fractions when doing comparisons in the `instance Eq`.

The problem is I am getting stuck when creating the `instance Eq` and I am not sure whether I also have to define a new `class Eq` for the `MyNum` data type. The general purpose of the `Eq` is to compare whether two fractions are equal when simplified with the helper method. Here is what I have so far:

Data Type and Constructors:

```
data MyNum = Fraction {num :: Integer, denom :: Integer} 
             | Mixed {whole :: Integer, num:: Integer, denom :: Integer}
```

Helper:

```
helper :: MyNum -> Rational
helper (Fraction num denom) = (fromIntegral num ) / (fromIntegral denom)
```

Current `Eq`:

```
instance (Eq n d) => Eq (MyNum n d) where
    Fraction n d == Fraction n d = True
--  Mixed _ _ _ == Mixed _ _ _ = True
```

The above `Eq` code  throws the following error:

> ```
> MyNum.hs:29:16: error:
>     * Conflicting definitions for `d'
>       Bound at: MyNum.hs:29:16
>                 MyNum.hs:29:32
>     * In an equation for `=='
>    |
> 29 |     Fraction n d == Fraction n d = True
>    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to exploit your `helper` function to convert both `MyNum`s into `Rational`s so that you can compare them:

```
instance Eq MyNum where
   x == y  =  helper x == helper y
```

Your *type* `MyNum` does not take any parameters, so you can't write `Eq (MyNum n d)`. The `n` and `d` are *values*, arguments for the `Fraction` data constructor, not the type. Since these values are handled by the helper, we don't need to care about them in the instance definition either.

Note that, for the above instance to work, `helper` must deal with both forms of number, `Fraction` and `Mixed`.

```
helper:: MyNum -> Rational
helper (Fraction num denom)    = fromIntegral num / fromIntegral denom
helper (Mixed whole num denom) = ...
```

Comment: How and when is helper being called in the instance Eq? Could you explain that line of code? By the way, your answer is pretty concise and to the point. Thanks.

Comment: @stcol The key line is `x == y = helper x == helper y` which means: whenever you have two values `x,y` of type `MyNum`, to compute `x==y` you can compute `helper x == helper y`, i.e. apply the helper to both `x` and `y` and compare the results.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this happens is because you use `n` and `d` twice in the head of your  `==` method definition, which is not allowed.

Both `Fraction n d` and `Fraction n d` in `Fraction n d == Fraction n d  =  True` are *patterns*, and using the same variable in more than one pattern on the left of the `=` sign in not allowed.

You would also need to write the type constraints as `(Eq n, Eq d) =>…`, and not `Eq n d`, but here it makes no difference since you do not use *type* parameters anyway, so no `Eq` constraint is needed at all -- the type of the values used by your `MyNum` type, which are all `Integer`s, already is an instance of `Eq`:

```
instance Eq MyNum where
    Fraction n1 d1 == Fraction n2 d2 | n1 == n2 && d1 == d2  =  True
    -- …
```

Prolog, which works with *unification* indeed allows us to use the same variable multiple times in the head, to indicate equality.

But Haskell works with *pattern matching*, and it is therefore not entirely clear what reusing the same variable would mean, especially since not every type is an instance of `Eq`.

Comment: Thanks Willem, that clarifies the use of arguments in the data type.

Comment: I think the instance context should just be deleted, not split.

Comment: @DanielWagner: aaarrggh... yes. Thanks!